# What is the right way to convert UTF16 string to wchar_t on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, unicode

In the project that still uses XCode 3 (no C++11 features like codecvt)

Comment: Note that `wchar_t` doesn't have any particular encoding. The encoding can be different from locale to locale. Locales with names ending in '.UTF-8' will use UTF-32, but other locales use different things.

Comment: the right way would be to use char for unicode, not wchar_t; e.g. utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conversion library, like libiconv.  You can set its input encoding to `"UTF-16LE"` or `"UTF-16BE"` as needed, and set its output encoding to `"wchar_t"` rather than any specific charset.

```
#include <iconv.h>

uint16_t *utf16 = ...; // input data
size_t utf16len = ...; // in bytes

wchar_t *outbuf = ...; // allocate an initial buffer
size_t outbuflen = ...; // in bytes

char *inptr = (char*) utf16;
char *outptr = (char*) outbuf;

iconv_t cvt = iconv_open("wchar_t", "UTF-16LE");

while (utf16len > 0)
{
    if (iconv(cvt, &inptr, &utf16len, &outptr, &outbuflen) == (size_t)(−1))
    {
        if (errno == E2BIG)
        {
            // resize outbuf to a larger size and
            // update outptr and outbuflen according...
        }
        else
            break; // conversion failure
    }
}

iconv_close(cvt);
```

Comment: libiconv seems to be under GPL, so think twice before using it if you don't want your project to be under GPL.

Comment: @EdwardFalk You're looking at the GNU implementation. Most Unix systems come with their own iconv implementation, since it's part of the POSIX standard. (Also the GNU library is LGPL, so it can be linked dynamically with a non-GPL'd program.)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want `wchar_t` on mac? `wchar_t` does not necessary be 16 bit, it is not very useful on mac.

I suggest to convert yo `NSString` using

```
char* payload; // point to string with UTF16 encoding
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithCString:payload encoding: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

To convert NSString to UTF16

```
const char* payload = [s cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

Note that mac support `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding` as well.

Note2: Although const char* is used, the data is encoded with UTF16 so don't pass it to `strlen()`.

Comment: NSString can't be used in my case (project is in C++, cross-platform, old and big).

Comment: Begin cross-platform does not need to get rid of OS-dependent code, you just write wrappers for those facilities. An other option would use 3rd party library that reassemble UTF functions provided by NSString, like ICU, the last option is the parse the string yourself using the open standard UTF tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the safest route.

1. Get the UTF-16 string as a UTF-8 string (using `NSString`)
2. set the locale to UTF-8
3. use `mbstowcs()` to convert the UTF-8 multi-byte string to a wchart_t

At each step you are ensured the string value will be protected.

Comment: @EdwardFalk [setlocale()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) is in locale.h and [mbstowcs()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) is in stdlib.h. There is not dependency on libiconv.

Comment: Mia culpa; I meant that comment to go on the previous answer.